# Hide "index not running" warning when Windows Search service disabled

Tags: windows, windows-search

How to hide the annoying bar appearing in explorer:

```
Your searches might be slow because the index is not running. Click to turn on the index...
```

after having the Windows Search service disabled? The machine is running Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Is there a reason you've turned it off in the first place? As far as I've seen leaving it on doesn't exactly slow the system down to a crawl. If you find it slow, go to Indexing options and only include directories you care about searching in.

Comment: @Rex: Try Everything from voidtools. It builds index within 10 minutes, includes all directories (e.g. %windir%), and the search is basically instant (it's similar to the Google search as you type feature). So I decided to disable this to save laptops battery.

Comment: Searching is pretty much instantaneous with indexing turned on as well..I can find both files named as well as containing the text I specify in less than a second- on Windows 8.1, but I don't think that makes much of a difference.

Comment: Indexing is vastly improved in 7 over what was in XP..you don't need anything extra like Everything, so I suggest you configure your indexing service to only index your documents (definitely remove c:\windows & system32 from it), let it rebuild indices and then see.